# SCons - convert all images in a directory

Tags: python, scons

I'd like to write an SConstruct file that will convert (e.g.) all the JPEG files in a directory into PNGs.

I think I have the Builder alright:

```
ConvToPNG = Builder(action = 'convert $SOURCE $TARGET',
        suffix = '.png',
        src_suffix = '.jpg')
env['BUILDERS']['ConvToPNG'] = ConvToPNG
```

But then I'm not sure how to make a list of all the targets that need to be built.  I can do it in a Python-y way like this:

```
pix_conversions = [env.ConvToPNG(jpg_src) for jpg_src in Glob('pix/img_*.jpg')]
```

And then maybe I'll use an Alias for those:

```
env.Alias('convert_all', pix_conversions)
```

Or else make a Node by hand and have it `Depends` on the conversions.

The thing is, this seems like it's something that Scanners are sorta made for.  But I couldn't get that to work well.  I tried making a Builder that would work on a directory and call a Scanner that would add a bunch of targets, but it didn't work because the SCons internals expect a Builder to run on a file.  (or at least, that's what I gleaned from the error messages).

Is there a more SCons-y way of doing this?

Comment: are you doing this for fun? If not look at convert, an ImageMagick tool (www.imagemagick.org)

Comment: Just an update:  SCons does it alright, but once I tried running it on our real data, with maybe 50,000 images in various directories, SCons started spending like half an hour thinking about what images to convert.  So I switched to `make` and everything is fine...  *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps seems fine, but Alias node you need to pass to the AlwaysBuild function:

```
env.AlwaysBuild(env.Alias('convert_all', pix_conversions))
```

So the end result would be:

```
ConvToPNG = Builder(action = 'convert $SOURCE $TARGET',
        suffix = '.png',
        src_suffix = '.jpg')
env['BUILDERS']['ConvToPNG'] = ConvToPNG
pix_conversions = [env.ConvToPNG(jpg_src) for jpg_src in Glob('pix/img_*.jpg')]
env.AlwaysBuild(env.Alias('convert_all', pix_conversions))
```

It will work fine without any scanners. SCons will check MD5 hash of your JPEG files and if some file changed since last conversion then builder will be launched again.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what the AlwaysBuild function does in this case?

Thank you!!

Comment: @Ross Rogers - I saw that page, but it's a little bit too abstract for me---does AlwaysBuild force convert_all to be always out of date?  Does that just mean that it will always check that the .png's are up to date, or does it mean that it will always rebuild them?

Thanks both of you!!

Comment: AlwaysBuild used for non filesystem objects to ensure they will be build when needed. Your Alias() has created virtual target, so you need to ensure that every time you'll run `scons convert_all` your conversion builder will be invoked. You may think about AlwaysBuild as rough equivalent of .PHONY in Makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Scanners are for *implicit* dependencies.

e.g. you want to build `foo` which depends on `foo.c` which does a `#include` of `bar.c`.  Thus, when you tell SCons to build `foo` with dependency `foo.c`, the [C scanner](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0.d20100117/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Scanner.C-module.html) will automatically pick up *implicit* dependency `bar.c` based on the *explicit* dependency `foo.c`.